# Options to structure compile-time constants in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

I need to pass a bunch of constants into my OpenCL kernel.  Luckily, these are mostly known at compile-time, meaning: kernel compile-time.  And therefore I can pass them in as a bunch of defines like `-D leftOuterMargin=3 -D rightOuterMargin=2 -D leftInnerMargin=1 -D rightInnerMargin=2 ...`.

But this gets a bit unwieldy, and makes it hard to write re-usable functions inside the kernel.  I'm looking for something a bit more structured, like say structs.  However, structs would seem to be stored either in constant space (if create using a global `constant` instantiation, probably via an appropriate #define), or private space (if create inside the kernel function, again probably via an appropriate #define)?

What options are available for structuring constant data in a kernel, that is known at compile-time?  Some things I hope for:

- structured, can just pass a single pointer-like thing into reusable methods, rather than having 8-16 clumsily-named #defines, or 8 parameters into each non-kernel method
- the values load quickly when used, just like normal #defined values
- the values can be used by the compiler for optimizations, eg if I use one for a loop upper-bound, that loop can be fully unwrapped at compile time
- won't increase register pressure
- relatively standard, will work generally, across different gpu platforms/manufacturers

Comment: Perhaps you can use some templating engine to generate the kernels? Depending on the engine (and the host language you use), it can give a lot of options.

Comment: Ok, I already have cogapp available in my build environment actually, which uses python to generate code.  What templating engines do you have in mind that have worked well for you?

Comment: I use OpenCL from Python as well, and [Mako](http://docs.makotemplates.org) worked very well for me. It has essentially Python syntax (inverted around strings, of course) and allows you to pass arbitrary Python objects as arguments, and use Python code inside.

Comment: Do you have some example code I can look at, to see how this could work?

Comment: Addendum: hmmm, you know, but my environment at runtime is actually pure c/c++ currently, no python, but I suppose that could change...

Comment: I mostly use it for some complicated code generation (see e.g. [a reduction template from my reikna library](https://github.com/Manticore/reikna/blob/develop/reikna/algorithms/reduce.mako)). I created a [slightly modified basic PyOpenCL example](https://gist.github.com/Manticore/09d25c4355d3a3a41041) that uses Mako to illustrate the basics.

Comment: P.S. I am sure C/C++ have some great templating engines too. I'm just not too familiar with these languages' ecosystems.

Comment: Templating engine for C++ exists now :-)  https://github.com/hughperkins/Jinja2CppLight

Answer (score 1):

This:

> - the values load quickly when used, just like normal #defined values
> - the values can be used by the compiler for optimizations, eg if I use one for a loop upper-bound, that loop can be fully unwrapped at compile time
> - won't increase register pressure

Is incompatible with this:

> - can just pass a single pointer-like thing into reusable methods [...] or 8 parameters into each non-kernel method

If you want the values to be *constant expressions* (in other words, "known to the compiler"), then the only options are `#define` and global-scope `const`. No passing values dynamically by parameter or by indirection.

I suggest you make a struct with your different options:

```
struct Options {
    int leftOuterMargin;
    int rightOuterMargin;
    int leftInnerMargin;
    int rightInnerMargin;
    // and so on ...
};
```

Then you can define a header included in all translation units where the constants are required:

```
// constants.h

static const Options constants = {
    .leftOuterMargin = 3,
    .rightOuterMargin = 2,
    .leftInnerMargin = 1,
    .rightInnerMargin = 2
};
```

The compiler should be able to optimize your code just as well as if you had used `#define`.

Comment: Ah, `static const` will put it in the same space as `#define`, rather than in `constant`, etc, whilst still being fairly easy to use?  For the function calls, I heard that all function calls are inlined?  So, maybe such a static const struct might be treated similarly to a #define, if passed into functions too?

Comment: `static const` and `#define` are not the same thing. When used to define values at compile time, I'd argue that the former is much cleaner and should be preferred. But it's orthogonal to any kind of OpenCL space. For OpenCL < 2.x, yes, all function calls are inlined. Passing such a struct as (`const`) argument could (should!) result in the compiler propagating the constants indeed, but I suggest you check the generated assembly to be sure.